# Loading Texture from subclass

Tags: c#, xna, content-pipeline

I'm making a Windows Phone game and I'm a beginner in XNA. My Problem is with the `Content.RootDirectory = "Content";` that is in my main file. When I start the debugging, it tell me that in my subclass files can't find the logo that is in the Content when I put another

> Content_logo.RootDirectory= "Content";

```
Logo_Texture2d = Content_logo.Load<Texture2D>("Logo");
```

If I try making another root Directory an error shows up saying that This property cannot be changed after content has been loaded into the ContentManager. My question is how can I load up my texture from the content directory from a subclass.

```
public class MainFile : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    ScreenStates screentState;

    Rectangle TouchS_Y_X;

    Logo logo;
    Menu0 menu;
    Choose_Pets choose_pets;
    ScreenStates.CurrentGameState GameState;

    public MainFile()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);

        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        // Frame rate is 30 fps by default for Windows Phone.
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333);

        // Extend battery life under lock.
        InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        this.screentState = new ScreenStates();
        ///choose_pets = new Choose_Pets();
        choose_pets = new Choose_Pets();

        logo = new Logo();

        menu = new Menu0();
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        GameState = ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.Logo;
        base.Initialize();

    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        TouchS_Y_X = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1);
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        this.menu.Load_Menu(GraphicsDevice, Content);
        choose_pets.Load_ChoosePet(Content, GraphicsDevice);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
        base.LoadContent();
    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        //this.logo.Unload_logo(Content);
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();

        #region Games States

        switch (GameState)
        {
            case ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.Logo:

                    logo.Update_logo(gameTime);

                    this.logo.Load(this.Content, this.GraphicsDevice);

                    if (logo.FadeOut_logo == true)
                    GameState = ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.Menu;

                    break;

            case ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.Menu:
                    menu.Update_Menu(gameTime);

                break;

            case ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.CharactersChooser:
                    //choose_pets.Update_petchoose(gameTime);
                break;
        }
        #endregion

        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Black);

        #region GameStateDraw
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        switch(GameState)
        {
            case ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.Logo:           
                logo.Draw(spriteBatch);
            break;

                //Menu Draw State
            case ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.Menu:
             menu.Draw_Menu(spriteBatch);
            break;

            case ScreenStates.CurrentGameState.CharactersChooser:
               // choose_pets.Draw_petChoose(spriteBatch);
            break;
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
 #endregion

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

And this is my subclass Logo that is my first enumerator to be show in the screen..

```
 class Logo
{
    Texture2D Logo_Texture2d;
    Rectangle Logo_Rec;
    Color Logo_color;

    public bool FadeOut_logo = false;

    public double _Timer_logo;

    SpriteFont Norm_fonts;

    public void Load(ContentManager Content_logo, GraphicsDevice graphics_logo)
    {
        Logo_Texture2d = Content_logo.Load<Texture2D>("Logo");
        Logo_Rec = new Rectangle(0, 0, graphics_logo.Viewport.Width, graphics_logo.Viewport.Height);

        Norm_fonts = Content_logo.Load<SpriteFont>("Fonts\\Normal_Font"); 
    }

    //public void Unload_logo(ContentManager Content_logo)
   // {
      //  if (FadeOut_logo == true)
      //      Content_logo.Unload();
    //}

    public void Update_logo(GameTime gametime_logo)
    {

        _Timer_logo += gametime_logo.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        if (gametime_logo.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds >= 10)
            Logo_color.A--; Logo_color.B--; Logo_color.G--; Logo_color.R--;

        if (Logo_color.B == 0)
            FadeOut_logo = true;

    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(Logo_Texture2d, Logo_Rec, Logo_color);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(Norm_fonts, "CurrentState: Logo" + "    Timer: " + ((int)_Timer_logo).ToString(), new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
    }
}
}
```

the debugging stop because it cant find the logo and my image format is .png so is not the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When XNA compiles, it imports and process all assets - textures, sound, music, fonts, etc. - into .xnb files. The standard filetype for texture is .png.

If the texture cannot be found, it probably means that it is not being imported. Add content by right-clicking ProjectNameContent (Content) -> Add -> Existing Item in the Solution Explorer.

When you've done this, make sure that the Content Importer and Content Processor properties of the texture are both set to "Texture - XNA Framework".

On a side note, you are calling Logo.Load() from within MainFile.Update() upon each step - it might be a good idea to change this.

Comment: my texture are in the content I use to load those image but when I write more deeply this error occour. those image where suceful work but i don't know what happen that this error keep showing up.

Comment: ohh and I thanks you for telling me the Logo.Load(); I didn't notice that xD

Answer (score 0):

Creating another content manager is not the way to get around this.

One way to solve this would to be to pass a reference to `Content` as a parameter of a method. For example:

```
class Foo
{
     public void LoadContent(ContentManager content)
     {
          Logo_Texture2d = content.Load<Texture2D>("Logo");
     }
}

public class Game1 : Game
{
     //...
     protected override void LoadContent()
     {
          Foo.LoadContent(Content);
     }
}
```

EDIT: also, are you loading in content through VS? Right-click [ProjectName]Content (Content) -> Add -> Existing Item? Just checking...

Comment: I have already something like that but I think the subclass are not reading the Content file I will put two code of my mainfile and my sub class logo.

Comment: Added another answer in response to OP's edit - covers a different topic than the one provided here.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `Content` in a subclass, you sholud pass the `Content` to that class, or maybe set that class to inherit from `GameComponent`, so you can simply access the content manager using `Game.Content`.
You don't need to declare another content.

Comment: if I don't have to declare it why is giving me that error the image is in the proper place I still not know why.